# How to keep the inner of the cards the same length in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, mozilla

To keep the inner of the cards the same length I am using CSS **height:100%** and **display:table**. In CHROME and EDGE it works OK. But it does not work in Mozilla Firefox. The inner pulls out of its parent.

More details in this yt video https://youtu.be/6uO-9UNGXFw

Here is my code https://codepen.io/Dvorakova/pen/yLOjqeP

```
.card>div {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the rule of `height: 100%` from the `.card > div`
2. Remove the rule of `display: table` from the `.card > div`
3. Add diplay property of 'flex' or 'grid' to your `.card` CSS class.

   ```
   .card > div {
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 2rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        border-radius: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .card {
        background: #f55053;
        background: linear-gradient(45deg,#f55053 0,#f9a18a 100%);
        border-radius: .75rem;
        padding: .75rem;
        transition: all .3s ease;
        display: flex;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to **card** class

```
.card {
    display:grid;
    height: auto;
}
```

And add `height:-webkit-fill-available;` instead of `height:100%` from **card>div**

```
.card>div {
    height:-webkit-fill-available;
}
```

### [`Codepen Demo`](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/NWNMOaP)